# What is meant by this statement about Intersection-Union tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Following the standard setup, for a hypothesis null H0 which can be subdivided into two other null hypotheses H01 and H02, the Intersection-Union test rejects H0 if both H01 and H02 are rejected. In the textbook it says:

"An interesting feature of intersection-union tests is that no multiplicity adjustment is necessary to control the size of a test but the individual hypotheses cannot be tested at levels higher than the nominal significance level either (Berger, 1982)."

My question is on the meaning of this statement. Let's say we define $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha$ as the significance levels for test 1, test 2, and the overall test (nominal) respectively. Is it saying that I am not allowed to choose $\alpha_1$ or  $\alpha_2$ to be larger than $\alpha$? If so, why is this the case? I tried reading through both the textbook section and Berger (1982) but could not find the answer. Also, if this is the case, then does this mean that the test only works when we choose $\alpha_1$=$\alpha_2$=$\alpha$?

Comment: I would read this as saying that if you both reject $H_{01}$ when $\alpha_1=0.05$ and reject  $H_{02}$ when $\alpha_2=0.01$ then you can reject $H_0 = H_{01} \cup H_{02}$ when $\alpha=0.05$ or more.  In other words, none of the individual $\alpha_i$ can exceed the overall nominal significance level $\alpha$ but they can be equal to it.

Comment: This is how I interpret it as well but I would like to get confirmation because the way it is phrased when read as is seems to imply different.